# How upper bound of harmonic sum is proven

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-functions

I know it’s that kind of $1 + \log_{2}{n}$, I don’t know where did that come from etc...

Comment: Welcome to MSE, you may want to consider reading the following link on how to format the question in LaTeX, making it more readable (especially if you intend to ask a more elaborated question in the future) https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The first term is $1$, the second term less, the third and fourth are each less than $\frac12$ so sum to less than $1$, and you can do something similar with the next four terms, the right after that etc. This covers the case where $n$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: $\int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} dx \leq (1)(\frac{1}{n})$ for $n=1,2,3,...$ since the maximum of $\frac{1}{x}$ when $x$ is between $n$ and $n+1$ is $\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a picture is worth a thousand words on this one

[image: Graph]

Comment: Thanks that did it